# NTLM v2 authentication issue

Tags: java, windows, windows-7, ntlmv2

I have a server side code in java which does NTLM authentication. Its working well in windows xp but in windows 7, its not working and the user is getting a login popup asking the user to verify again and again. Currently the jcifs version i am using is 0.8 and jdk is 1.4.

The sample piece of code is as follows:---

```
**String domainController = configFacade.getParameter("windows.domaincontroller", UserValidator.DOMAINCONTROLLER);

NtlmPasswordAuthentication authentication = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(domain, racfUserId, password);

try {
UniAddress dc = UniAddress.getByName(domainController);
SmbSession.logon(dc, authentication);
}**
```

Kindly tell me what changes i need to make..........